# Pass binary data into stored procedure with the use of XML

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, silverlight-4.0, binary-data

I am working on a Silverlight application.

Is there any way to pass binary data from an application to a stored procedure?

My stored procedure only accepts one `XML` parameter

I have a file-browse control through which I select a file

I want to save that file in database `Image` dataype column.

Also I have to pass other parameter in xml like Name,Password,address etc...

Comment: You're not saying what database you're using - but if you're using SQL Server 2005 or newer, you should no longer use the `Image` datatype - it's deprecated and will be removed sooner or later. Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead.

Comment: i am use SqlServer2008  and no issue if i use Varbinary(max) but still my question is how to pass it using XML